# Locking not allowed on Non-Select queries in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there any way to implement Optimistic or Pessimistic lock on Non Select query in Spring? I am using JPA to make operations on database. I have implemented a few custom queries as well. However, I cannot set an optimistic or pessimistic lock on Non-Select queries like Insert or Update. Can this be done in any way?

Comment: Insert and Update are bypassing JPA and directly produce an SQL statement. But this is not a problem because Optimistic and Pessimistic Locking for insert or update makes no sense.

Comment: So are the ACID properties maintained automatically by using JPA? Or for that matter, are the ACID properties maintained by using JdbcTemplate too?

Comment: If you do Insert or update the database will set the locks. Why are you using update and insert and not Entities?

Comment: I am using Entities. I have classes with the annotation @Entity. For insert, update and such CRUD operations, I am using save(), delete(), fetch() methods of CrudRepository.

Comment: and for what purpose do you need the custom insert and updates?

Comment: For making complex queries like insert with select, update with joins and so on.

Comment: In that case you will not need Pessimistic Locking. But you must set the Version field for Optimisitc Locking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218283/discussion-between-suyash-ghuge-and-simon-martinelli).